# C: Argv declaration in the main function

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv

What do you think which way is better declaring the argv argument in the main function and why?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv /* char *argv[] */ /* char (*argv)[] */) {
    //...
}
```

argv comes into the function ultimately as a pointer - just as a copy of the argv address, but not as an array, right? So I think, the other alternatives must also be syntactically correct, but which way would you prefer?

Regards

Comment: Which way do *you* prefer? I think most programmers will understand even the last declaration.

Answer (score 6):

`char *argv[]` is most explicit as to what it means -- an array of strings.

`char **argv` is fastest to type if you're lazy.

`char (*argv)[]` I'm not sure why you'd use.

Answer (score 3):

Using `*argv[]` is the traditional way, but I have seen programs using `**argv` as well.

The variant `(*argv)[]` is actually the opposite of `*argv[]`, the first is a pointer to an array (which is wrong in this case), the last is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer

```
char *argv[]
```

because it describes `argv` better, IMO. It's an array of `char*`, that is an array of strings, which is what I expect `argv` to be. Not a double pointer. The third variant seems ok and is equivalent to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I like `char *argv[]` as it is the clearest expression of what is actually passed; an array of pointers to character strings.

`char **argv` is more consise but I feel "pointer to pointer" does not accuratly describe wahts being passed.

The extra parenthesis in the third option just confuse things.